# Make a conjecture about the values of $k$ for which multiplicative inverses exist for every element in $\mathbb{Z}_k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

I know that $gcd(k, \bar{k}) = 1$ for $k$ to have a multiplicative inverse. Can someone give me pointers where to start?

Comment: $0$ will never have a multiplicative inverse (i.e. the residue class corresponding to the multiples of $k$).  Other than that, think about which numbers $k$ are such that $\gcd(k, n) = 1$ for **all** $n$ that aren't a multiple of $k$ itself.  Notice that $\gcd(k, n) > 1$ would mean $k$ and $n$ share a common factor.

Comment: @KajHansen if $k$ and $n$ have $gcd$ greater than one?

Comment: If that happens, then $\overline{n}$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_k$.

Comment: Is there a way to formulate that only when $gcd(k, n)=1$ there's inverse?